# CQ5.6.1 Text component in the footer to pass same content across all pages

Tags: aem

I have a footer.jsp which is expected to appear same across all pages. I added a Text component in the footer.jsp. When the author adds content to this Text component in Home page, I want the content to reflect in the footer of all child pages. Here is how I use the text component in the footer.jsp, but this is not working as I want.

```
<div class="gelUpdateContent">
    <cq:include path="text" resourceType="foundation/components/text" />
    Get Live Great <span class="txtRed">updates </span>
</div>
```

I already tried iparsys component instead of text, which is useful, but then my requirement is to restrict it to text only.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of providing relative path to the `path` property in `cq:include` i.e. (`text`), provide an absolute path, something like (`/content/<project>/<homepage>/jcr:content/text`).

Providing relative path creates the text node under each page, whereas absolute path ensures that all the pages read and write to the node present in the path provided always.

This is one way of achieving what you need.

More info on using cq:include can be found [here](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/howto/taglib.html#%3Ccq:include%3E)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @rakhi's answer of providing absolute path. But there is another way to do this.

Try using iParsys. iParsys configuration is inherited by all child pages. if you include an iParsys and drag-n-drop your footer component in the root page of your site, then that footer component will start appearing in all your child pages.

Answer (score 0):

Well, We can design with following options:

1. It is depend on your requirement. If you want to have common footer across the site then Put some global path(i.e /content/rootSitePath/) as a cq:include path.
2. If you want to have footer information get updated on child pages only then use IParsys component.

I would prefer to use option 1, but make sure we are hard coding path. Bette to have utility to determine path.

Thanks,
Jitendra